# Can't use dynamically generated string as jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto, quotation-marks

I would like to use the value from `i` to build a new ID to use in my `scrollto` function, but it doesn't work.

```
$('.calendar').each( function(i){

  $(this).attr('id',i).css({'margin-left':'2.5px'}).text(i+5).on('click',function(){

    var rr="$('"+"#jour"+i+"')"
    alert(rr)

    $(".layerJour").scrollTo(rr, {duration:300})

  })

});
```

When I use an alert, it works exactly as I want:

```
var rr="$('"+"#jour"+i+"')"
alert(rr)
```

but when used here it's not working:

```
$(".layerJour").scrollTo(rr, {duration:300})
```

If I do the following, it works, which is strange because it uses exactly the same name that I have when I use `alert`.

```
$(".layerJour").scrollTo($('#jour1'), {duration:300})
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: var rr=$("#jour"+i); so if i = 1 var rr would = $("#jour1");

Comment: i tried it again . it's fine .thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put quotes into the strings, just concatenate the strings normally.

```
$("#jour" + i)
```

The quotes are part of the literal string syntax, they're not actually in the strings themselves.

Comment: isn't that what I said?

Comment: Yes, but you didn't post it as an answer, and the comment didn't go into detail about why.